# Color scale reassigning value

Tags: d3.js

I have colors corresponding to a certain domain,

```
var colors = d3.scale.category20();
colors.domain([d1, d2, d3]);
```

I would like to reassign color for some domain values,

```
colors(d2) = "#ffffff";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the range again with the changed value, for example by creating a new scale:

```
var range = d3.scale.category20().range();
range[1] = "#ffffff";
var scale = d3.scale.ordinal().range(range);
```

Comment: Is there a way without creating a new scale ?  I would like to set the domain only once, then only changing the range if possible ?

Comment: You could set the range for the built-in scale, but that may lead to bugs further on. With the code I've posted, you need to set the domain only once.